# Multi-line X-Axis labels

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have a DataTable that is the source for a 3 series chart in one chart area.

The first DataTable column is Date format, repeated 24 times for each hour, while the second column is the hour of the day, 0-23.

I use the first Date column as the XValueMember for all 3  series (one is enough!).

I can get the Date and hour label in the same line by setting the X-interval to DateTime.Hour, but I want the Hour label as a **second-line text**.

This is what I have:   03-04-2014 18:00

This is what I want:   03-04-2014
 
............................... 18:00

How can I do that?

Comment: What chart are you talking about? What environment (Windows Forms, ASP.NET, WPF, Phone) ?

Comment: It's VS2010, WinForm, MSChart, .NET4.5